# JavaScript file dependend on JavaScript code block in Yii2 (for dojo configuration)

Tags: javascript, php, dojo, yii2

I'm trying to register the dojo javascript files with Yii 2.0.
According to the dojo documentation, the code block for dojo config must be loaded before the actual dojo.js in order to be considered. However, in the HTML output my custom javascript code is always loaded after dojo.js.

This is my code:

```
$this->registerJs('dojoConfig="async:true,isDebug:true";', $this::POS_HEAD,'dojoconfiguration');
$this->registerJsFile('/dojo_toolkit/dojo/dojo.js', ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()], 'position' => yii\web\View::POS_HEAD]);
```

And in HTML it looks like this:

```
<script src="/dojo_toolkit/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojoConfig="async:true,isDebug:true";</script>
```

Any advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the same position Yii2 always puts the inline scripts first and then the actual external files. So you can't fix this by adding them both to the `<head>`.

Its best to give the `registerJsFile()` call a `POS_END` to load it at the very end. It will still be loaded before the `document.ready()` call is made.

That way you can be sure that the configuration in the header is parsed before the load. Worst case scenario you can use `POS_BEGIN` to load it right after the body tag is opened, but since loading javascript is blocking I would try to avoid that.